# How to read & add all text from a text file to AutoComplete?

Tags: c#, .net, autocomplete, io, autofill

How to read & add all text from a text file to AutoComplete?
( C# Windows Application )

what i want is like:-

```
foreach (string str in File.ReadAllLines("sometext.txt"))
{
    AutoComplete.Items.Add(str);//this code not works it's just example
}
```

Comment: `please someone tell me is it possible to ...` Yes it is possible.

Comment: What happens when you try it? Does it work?

Comment: it's not working that's why i am asking. It's just an example what i want to do.

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't tell us anything. What, specifically, is not working?

Answer (score 1):

In your textbox (textBox1) properties set your AutoCompleteMode to what you want, then your source to "Custom" Then load each line or char or whatever is in the file into a string array, and finally use the AddRange function:

string[] colors= new string[] {
"Red",
"Blue",
"Green",
"Yellow"
};
 textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(colors);

So for your case, use: StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("somefile.txt");

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
//add your lines here to the string array, whatever your criteria may be for each element in the array
}

textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(/*your string array here*/);

Comment: This answer works like a charm! Pity it's not accepted though.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your Form_load or any other way so it can be initiated.

```
 string[] autosource= File.ReadAllLines("C:\\autocomplete.txt");
        for(int i = 0; i < autosource.Length; i++)
        {
            txt_searchfiled.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(autosource[i]);
        }
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

In case of enabled `MultiLine` for textbox, do uncheck `Multiline` option and load this code to form load. This will load lines from `autocomplete.txt` present in project directory.

```
string[] autosource= File.ReadAllLines(@"autocomplete.txt");
for(int g = 0; g < autosource.Length; g++)
{
    textboxname.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(autosource[g]);
}
textboxname.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
```